# Route direction based on road width?

Tags: qgis, road, route, qgis-network-analysis

I have road polyline data that contains a **road width** field (in meters) and I want to visualize road direction, based on this road width field.

The road direction that I mean is kind of like this:
[image][(taken from here)](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/basic_network_analysis.html)

But instead of using information whether the road is one-way or two-way, I want the arrow to always pointing towards the road with wider road width.

Is it possible in QGIS?

Comment: The question is not clear to me. You should provide more details and a screenshot.

Comment: @Babel Basically kind of like this: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/basic_network_analysis.html
But the arrow symbol is pointing towards the road with wider width.

Comment: If you do not want people to read whole tutorials, please include the relevant information to your initial question by editing it.

Comment: @Babel I'm sorry, I'm not really good at explaining what I want to ask in Eng. I'm editing the question now.